Helmet Rejects Hash?
I'm getting a message from Helmet saying:

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval'
'unsafe-inline' 'sha256-UFAIyF7js3hAjNTAMfA9aw9/M2vFShASZl928oyfHng='
self sha256-2v+H7ivKixFdwYIDLCzZrEn+yqT+b/i5sriBsrjHaAk=

...so I added the hash to the script-src directive:
  {
      "allowedOrigins_script_src": [
        "self",
        "sha256-2v+H7ivKixFdwYIDLCzZrEn+yqT+b/i5sriBsrjHaAk=",
        [.....]]

But, it looks like I added the hash incorrectly, because now I'm getting this message:

ep.localhost/:1 The source list for the Content Security Policy
directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source:
'sha256-2v+H7ivKixFdwYIDLCzZrEn+yqT+b/i5sriBsrjHaAk='. It will be
ignored.

What's wrong with the way I've specified this hash in the directive?

Helmet maintainer here. It looks like self and sha256-2v+... need to be quoted. It's possible that there are other issues I don't see right now.

Is there a way to find out exactly which inline-script this hash is associated with? I've tried echo -n "alert('Hello, world.');" | openssl dgst -sha256 | base64 on all the inline-scripts I can find, but none of the hashes I've found so far, match that hash.

You might be making a mistake I make a lot: not including whitespace on either end of the script. However, it seems like the issue is that your Content Security Policy has two issues: (1) it doesn't include a hash for some script it's trying to run (2) it includes an invalid hash.

@VikR I also use hashes in my helmet options for our Meteor app, which is working fine so far. You can checkout the file on GitHub maybe it helps.
